# Simple dendogram trouble in r programming using hclust

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hclust

I have a dataset where i am trying to cluster a column with 986 observations with the below code.

```
PremiumPrice_Sclaed <- scale(data$PremiumPrice)
plot(PremiumPrice_Sclaed)

d <- dist(PremiumPrice_Sclaed) #scale for cluster
fit.average <- hclust(d, method="average")
plot(fit.average, cex = .1 ,main="Average Linkage Clustering")
```

can someone please tell me how to fix the below dendogram?

[image]

Comment: You have 1000 items along the x-axis, that is a lot of information to display in a small area.  What is an acceptable fix?  Breaking up the dendrogram into multiple parts for better visibility?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to remove the labels.

```
hc <- hclust(dist(rbind(USArrests, USArrests, USArrests)), "ave")

par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(hc, hang=-1, sub='w/ labels')
plot(hc, hang=-1, labels=FALSE, sub='w/o labels')
```

[image]